# Flask form processing

Tags: python, flask

What is the correct way processing of forms, which are optional and use no validation?

```
#forms.py:
class PageForm(Form):
    field1 = TextField('field1')
    field2 = SelectField('field2', choices=choices)

#views.py
def page():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form.get('field1'):
            #some action
        if request.form.get('field2'):
            #some other action
```

Is it okay to process forms like this? Looks lousy.

Comment: What do you mean by okay? Can you do it this way? sure. Is there a better way to do it? probably.
If your looking for a good tutorial on flask check out this one - http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks for the tutorial, I've read it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, such handling is correct if form validation is not required. Just one suggestion:

Use the `method` param of the `app.route` decorator:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST',])
```

After decoration with `method==['POST',]` declared, your view accepts **only POST** requests and you could strip the `if statement`.

Also, you could consider adding a `form` variable, so your code would become more verbose, and not planned data from `request.form` would be **stripped**:

```
form = PageForm(request.form)
# Than, access fields as form.<FIELD_NAME>.data
```

Comment: Yes, I have the decorator, just didn`t paste it.

Comment: @Bojczuk oh, greate. Also i've extended answer.